# Managed Switch (HP 1820) doesn't synchonise time with NTP Server

Tags: switch, ntp

I'm trying to set up a managed switch (HP 1820). So far everything works, but the time doesn't synchronise. The switch is configured correctly in terms of the IP-Settings (IP/Sub/Gateway - no DNS option). The IP address for NTP Server is correct, the port should be fine as well. I checked other clients (Windows clients) on the network, they are in sync. I'm out of ideas any suggestions what else to check?

[image: NTP Settings]

**UPDATE:**
Since I don't have access to the firewall to check I replaced the switch with a different device (I left the same IP, same host name, same cable etc.) the could explicitly test the NTP-Server query. Turns out the NTP-query on the test device times out as well, other services work fine. When I change IP/DNS etc. but leave the HW-connection on the test device I get the same results. But changing to a different HW-port it works. So most likely the problem it's  caused by a network device which I don't have access to (I strongly suspect the firewall) , or can anyone think of a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a late answer: It turns out that it actually was the firewall blocking NTP Server requests done by the switch.

Answer (score 2):

#### What else to check?

> Last Attempt Status - Request Timed Out

This is a big clue.

You should check whether the time server (time-e.netgear.com) is up (using http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/time-e.netgear.com.html):

[image]

It isn't, so use a more reliable time server.

I use a server from [pool.ntp.org: the internet cluster of ntp servers](https://www.ntppool.org/en/):

> The pool.ntp.org project is a big virtual cluster of timeservers providing reliable easy to use NTP service for millions of clients.

More diagnostics:

```
> ping 209.249.181.53

Pinging 209.249.181.53 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 209.249.181.53:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

> nslookup 209.249.181.53
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.42.129

Name:    time-e.netgear.com
Address:  209.249.181.53
Aliases:  53.181.249.209.in-addr.arpa


> tracert 209.249.181.53

Tracing route to time-e.netgear.com [209.249.181.53]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.42.129
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3   305 ms   418 ms   388 ms  10.124.205.185
  4   320 ms   368 ms   587 ms  10.247.85.171
  5   309 ms   367 ms   380 ms  10.247.85.114
  6    52 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.247.85.113
  7  1024 ms   499 ms   406 ms  10.247.85.178
  8   419 ms   428 ms   369 ms  87.237.20.150
  9   316 ms   381 ms   378 ms  87.237.20.71
 10   331 ms   378 ms   388 ms  212.187.166.149
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12   334 ms   368 ms   358 ms  4.68.70.78
 13   350 ms   398 ms   429 ms  ae10.mpr2.lhr2.uk.zip.zayo.com [64.125.31.194]
 14   492 ms   588 ms   561 ms  ae27.cs1.lhr11.uk.eth.zayo.com [64.125.30.236]
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16  1234 ms   729 ms   518 ms  ae3.cs1.ord2.us.eth.zayo.com [64.125.29.209]
 17   531 ms   538 ms   619 ms  ae5.cs1.den5.us.eth.zayo.com [64.125.29.19]
 18   183 ms   187 ms   191 ms  ae6.cs1.sjc2.us.eth.zayo.com [64.125.31.219]
 19   186 ms   189 ms   199 ms  ae0.cs2.sjc2.us.eth.zayo.com [64.125.28.141]
 20   186 ms   199 ms   186 ms  ae27.cr2.sjc2.us.zip.zayo.com [64.125.30.233]
 21   182 ms   184 ms   178 ms  ae3.er2.sjc2.us.zip.zayo.com [64.125.28.57]
 22   186 ms   185 ms   187 ms  209.66.115.82.t01309-01.above.net [209.66.115.82]
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, of course I tried different TNP-Servers. The server in there is just one of the ones I tried, at the time it was working fine. As far as I understand I can not use the pool because it requires a domain name, the switch just allows for an IP-address. Not sure if there's a "ntp-pool" that can be accessed via a static IP.

Comment: "Last Attempt Status - Request Timed Out" - that's because it never connected to a NTP-Server yet. Before it was on "manual time". Short update: Currently I suspect the firewall (I don't have access yet), I tried a client using the same "WAN"-port as I use with the switch...  eh voilà, same problem any requests via NTP time out (other ports work fine for some reason).

Comment: see my update...